# Why i get mysql result column value dismatch

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, min

msyql query

```
SELECT id,student_user_id,MIN(start_time) FROM appoint_course 
WHERE student_user_id IN(
    931,2034,2068,2111,2115,2173,2181,2285,2500,2505,2507,
    2518,2594,2596,2600,2608,2637,2652,2654
) 
AND course_type=3 and disabled=0  GROUP BY student_user_id;
```

result
[query result]

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| id    | student_user_id | MIN(start_time) |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  8356 |             931 |      1500351000 |
|  9205 |            2034 |      1501733400 |
|  9246 |            2068 |      1501649100 |
|  9755 |            2111 |      1502943000 |
|  9585 |            2115 |      1502595300 |
| 10820 |            2173 |      1503545700 |
|  9594 |            2181 |      1502852400 |
| 10324 |            2285 |      1502852400 |
| 11204 |            2500 |      1504839600 |
| 11152 |            2507 |      1504064100 |
| 12480 |            2594 |      1505707800 |
| 11521 |            2608 |      1504494000 |
| 11818 |            2652 |      1504753200 |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

but right start time is:

```
id: 9594
start_time: 1503284400
```

9594 right start_time is 1503284400 not 1502852400.In fact 1502852400 is a record of 9597
I do not know why.

Comment: Hello Tom. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question, so that people can help you with it.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show us sample input data and the output you expect.

Comment: start_time dismatch primary id.eg.right record:start_time:1,id:1,but i got start_time:1,id:2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any other database your query would return an error, because `id` is not in the `group by`.  The correct query is:

```
SELECT student_user_id, MIN(start_time)
FROM appoint_course
WHERE student_user_id IN (931,2034,2068,2111,2115,2173,2181,2285,2500,2505,2507,2518,2594,2596,2600,2608,2637,2652,2654) AND
      course_type = 3 and disabled = 0
GROUP BY student_user_id;
```

In your case, adding a simple `MIN(id)` to the `SELECT` might work, assuming that `id`s increase with the start time.

More generally, you appear to want:

```
SELECT ac.*
FROM appoint_course ac
WHERE ac.student_user_id IN (931,2034,2068,2111,2115,2173,2181,2285,2500,2505,2507,2518,2594,2596,2600,2608,2637,2652,2654) AND
      ac.course_type = 3 AND ac.disabled = 0 AND
      ac.start_time = (SELECT MIN(ac2.start_time)
                       FROM appoint_course ac2
                       WHERE ac2.student_user_id = ac.student_user_id AND
                             ac2.course_type = ac.course_type AND
                             ac2.disabled = ac.disabled
                      );
```

No `GROUP BY` is necessary.

I should add that there is a MySQL hack that often works:

```
SELECT student_user_id, MIN(start_time),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY start_time), ',', 1) as id_at_min_start_time
FROM appoint_course
WHERE student_user_id IN (931,2034,2068,2111,2115,2173,2181,2285,2500,2505,2507,2518,2594,2596,2600,2608,2637,2652,2654) AND
      course_type = 3 and disabled = 0
GROUP BY student_user_id;
```

This uses string manipulations and the `GROUP_CONCAT()` can overflow internal buffer sizes.

Comment: I did not get error,but result is not all right.I need id for doing something

Comment: @Tom . . . Which of these is not producing the result you expect?  All should be returning the `id` associated with the minimum start time for each student user.

Comment: subquery worked correctly,thank you.I'll try group_cat